# JComboBox getting selected String

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have problem with my JComboBox
on my W7 computer is everything ok,
but on my friends tablet it isn't.
When I click into JComboBox and write something, then click on button,

> //do something

is runnig

but when my friend do the same, is if false . JComboBox doesnt change and "" stay selected.
But there is something typed, in JComboBox

I think that  tablet with W8 and touchScreen works differently,
but JCombobox has not got something like `getValue()` or `getText()`

Could you help me ?:-)

```
jmenoPromenne1 = new JComboBox(moznosti.toArray());

jmenoPromenne1.setSelectedItem("");
    jmenoPromenne1.setEditable(true);
    }


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (((String) jmenoPromenne1.getSelectedItem()).compareTo("") != 0) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: By default, the when nothing is selected, selectedItem will return null

Comment: but this is not answer, is it ?

Comment: No it's info, to make sure you understand how it works

Comment: because of this, i call jmenoPromenne1.setSelectedItem(""); ;

Comment: Does it contain an entry called `""`?  If it doesn't this may not change the selection.  Calling `setSelectedItem(null)` allows the combobox to "deselect" any item (so `-1` becomes the selected item)